# Couldn't execute 'show fields from abcvideo': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1151_0.MYD' (Errcode: 24) (1)

Tags: mysql

I am getting the below error while running mysql auto backup script.

> > mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from abcvideo':  
> >   Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1151_0.MYD' (Errcode: 24) (1)

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/not-enough-file-handles.html